# Informix java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.informix.jdbc.IfxDirectConnection

Tags: java, informix

I'm trying to install and connect to a local Informix 14 for testing on Windows 10. My maven POM has:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.informix</groupId>
    <artifactId>informix-jdbc-complete</artifactId>
    <version>4.50.4.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I'm trying direct connection

```
database.url = jdbc:informix-direct://sysmaster
database.driver=com.informix.jdbc.IfxDirectConnection
```

But I'm getting class not found.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which class is identified as not being found?

Comment: IfxDirectConnection but it doesn't seem to be correct to use it. I just installed informix locally on Windows 10 and I can't get localhost to connect with any port that it says its using. The service is running.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use 'jdbc:informix-direct:'. That was reserved for UDR written in Java.

Use "jdbc:informix-sqli", something like:

```
Class.forName("com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:informix-sqli://420ito:9088/stores7:INFORMIXSERVER=ids1410;user=informix;password=mypassword;");
```

Comment: That's my other problem. When I installed Informix I checked the port numbers but none of them work. I always get java.sql.SQLException: Socket connection to server (localhost:9090) failed. Check your server is reachable from this client on the host:port specified.
jdbc:informix-sqli://localhost:9090/sysmaster

Comment: No idea why no port numbers seem to work. Installed on Windows 10 and "IBM Informix Dynamic Server Message Service" service is running.

Comment: Maybe the install did not create a listener on the loopback (localhost) and is using other network interfaces.
First check that you can connect with dbaccess (a GUI tool within the server bin directory). If you can your server should be up. Then run 'onstat -g ntt', it should show which network interfaces are used by the listeners, something like (*420ito|9092|soctcp)  means the Informix server is listening for SQLI socket connections (the protocol used by JDBC) in all the interfaces in a machine named "420ito" in the 9092 port.
Then use that port for your JDBC connection.